# Gitlab: import my old gitlab repository folder

Tags: git, docker, gitlab

I am setting up a new gitlab instance in docker but I have problems with importing my old gitlab repository folder (I forgot to backup the DB).

**I found on the gitlab issue board that I can use the following command to import all the folders:**

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos[/repositories]
```

**but when I tried to run this I got the following error on all the repos I tried to import**

```
Processing /repositories/Outboxit/YourMusic.git
 * Using namespace: Outboxit
 * Failed trying to create YourMusic (Outboxit/YourMusic)
   Errors: {:base=>["Unable to save project. Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/Outboxit"]}
Processing /repositories/Outboxit/MyBeer.git
 * Using namespace: Outboxit
 * Failed trying to create MyBeer (Outboxit/MyBeer)
   Errors: {:base=>["Unable to save project. Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/Outboxit"]}
```

Can sombody maybe help me with this because I really need to get my old repos back in an I am working on this for 3 days no trying stuff.

Comment: are you sure you set the correct permission in that `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data` 
 directory..?

Comment: Yea the permissions where already set by the docker instance zo I think it should be correct? I will add a picture with the permissions later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it using git instead of gitlab with the following script that I wrote:

```
CURRENT_PROJECT="<project-name>"
CURRENT_GROUP="<group-name>"
git clone C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/repositories/$CURRENT_GROUP/$CURRENT_PROJECT.git $CURRENT_PROJECT
cd $CURRENT_PROJECT
git remote set-url origin http://<server-address>/$CURRENT_GROUP/$CURRENT_PROJECT.git

for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master `; do
   git branch --track ${branch#remotes/origin/} $branch
done

git push --all
```